# The injectivity of $f^\sharp : \mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field (not necessary algebraically closed) and $A=k[t^2,t^3]$, $B=k[t]$, $f:A \to B$ be a inclusion map. I want to show that $f^\sharp : \mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A),\ P\mapsto P\cap A$ is homeomorphism in the Zariski topology.

> I know that $f^\sharp$ is a closed map and surjective because $B$ is the integral closure of $A$, but I can't show $f^\sharp$ is a injective. How to prove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $P,Q$ are two prime ideals of $B$, both distinct from $(t)$ (which specifically means that none of them contain $t$), such that $P\cap A=Q\cap A$. Pick a $p\in P$.

Now look at $t^2p$. It's in $P\cap A$, so it must be in $A\cap Q$, and therefore we must have $t^2p\in Q$. But $Q$ is a prime ideal not containing $t$, which means $p\in Q$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, we must have $P\subseteq Q$. An analogous argument shows that $Q\subseteq P$.

Lastly, let's say $P=(t)$. Then $t^2\in Q$, and again, since $Q$ is prime we must have $Q=(t)$.

Comment: I'm surprised that you were able to prove this without using any of the Cohen-Seidenberg theorems.  I thought for sure [incomparability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down#Lying_over_and_incomparability) would come up!